# How to give a priority to directives in Vue.js (2.0)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I'm looking to implement common functionality on some of the buttons/clickable in my application.

I'm hoping to put this functionality in a directive that registers an Event Listener before the @click directive (presumably) registers its own. The point is to not have to call this function in the @click 'callback function',  but declare it with a directive in the template.

```
Vue.directive('before-click', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    //register on('click', (event) => {
        //do things
    // })
  }
})
```

This ability seems to exist in earlier versions of vue.js but I cannot find it documented in more recent ones. (https://012.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive_Priority)

Adding the pair `priority: 1000` seems to have no effect

Comment: You have XY problem. Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? How should exactly before-click and @click work together?

Comment: For now this is to apply styling 'common' styles before 'non-common' '@click' methods are called.
The 'before-click' event-listener should modify the styling of the element (add/remove classes), then the '@click' function should run. For my purposes, the ordering of these is important, leading to the question on how to influence priority.

Comment: @Morgan How about preventing the default click event, doing your common styling and then programmatically re-invoking the click event?